# "Are" or "Is" when linking two singular nouns in a sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number, auxiliary-verbs

When you are talking about about two singular nouns and link them together in a sentence with a conjunction such as "and" which verb form is correct?

For example, would you say "Where is the broom and mop?" or  "Where are the broom and mop?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two are considered as **a unit**, you use the singular verb:

> - Where **is** *the pestle and mortar*?
> - *Mumford and sons* **is** my favourite band.

However, when **each noun** is considered to be **a separate unit**, you use a plural verb:

> - *My sister and my mother* **keep** contradicting me.
> - *The battery and the engine* **seem** to have died.

Unless you really consider *a broom* and *a mop* together to be a single unit, you shouldn't use them with a singular verb. Also, repeat the definite article *the*. If you say *the broom and mop*, it looks like a single unit just as it does with *a pestle and mortar*. If you say *the broom and the mop* it is clear that they are two different objects:

> Where **are** *the broom and the mop*?