# singular or plural, is/are some price you have to pay

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

everyone, what should I use in the sentence below? Should I use "are" to agree with the subject, which are two matters, or should I use "is" to agree with the object "price", which is an uncountable noun?

If you want to be famous, except for a loss of privacy, picking up bad habits and addiction to fame **is/are** often also some price you have to pay.

Comment: Related question, [“Are” or “Is” when linking two singular nouns in a sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265023/are-or-is-when-linking-two-singular-nouns-in-a-sentence). Believe me, there are hundreds of questions asked about this subject and there is only one answer to that which is in the linked question.

Comment: @Rathony Thanks for the comment. I have read the answer to that question. It did clear up a lot of confusion. But I was wondering if my question is a bit different. The object of my sentence is a uncountable noun and is different from any of the examples provided there. I am still not sure if I should use "is" or "are" here.

Comment: The problem with your sentence is it is not well written. Who wrote this sentence? Yourself? Where did you find the sentence? You need to tell the community whether you wrote the sentence or you found it on the internet. Assuming you wrote it yourself, it needs some correction.

Comment: @Rathony I wrote it myself, because I could not find one on the internet that can present my confusion. I am all ears to your opinion.

Comment: As Rathony suggested, the sentence is very poorly written. But anyway, the linking verbs always have to agree with the subject, so "are" is correct. Also, the uncountableness of the noun does not affect the singular state of it. So "price" is still singular. related-http://www.englishpage.net/showthread.php?2235-agreement-between-subject-and-object(-)